# Find visitors to multiple subdomains on single visit with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I'm working on a site that has quite the backlog of Google Analytics data for their site network. One of our big questions is whether people enter on one site and move to another (and if so, of course, how do these visits differ from single site visits).

The hostname report (Audience > Network > Hostname) shows all the host names and I've setup Advanced Segments to get site-specific data. That all works great, but I'm really having a hard time figuring out how to find visits to multiple sites as defined by visiting more than one subdomain or the root site and one or more subdomains.

I do see that other hostnames somehow come through when I apply one of the segments to the host name report. Which I can't say I expected. Is that the best way to see if people are visiting 2+ sites?

Answer (score 1):

As you are probably already doing, segment by referral traffic. The standard Landing Pages report will list the referring URLs. You should be able to filter by the the name of your site to see if any of the referring traffic is from another one your sites.

Doing this is good for one visit, but you may not be able to track this visitor if they go on another site. I don't know of an easy way to track visitors that go from Site A to Site B then to Site C.